# how to render contents to slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

as shown in the code posted below, in the child-component i created a `button` with a `slot`. the `slot` name is `slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel. the` button`in the child-component should have a property named`disabilityState` to indicate whther or not the button
is disabled.

in the parent-component, i want to render the `button` of the child-component and pass value of `disabilityState` from the parent to the child.

when i run the code, nothing is rendered. please let me know what my mistake is and how to fix it.

**child-component: DigitizePolygonButton.vue**

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabilityState="isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled">
    <slot name="slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel">text</slot>
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup(props) {
        return {
            digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState: props.isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**parent-component**:

```
<template v-slot:slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel>
    <DigitizePolygonButton :disabilityState="false"> test </DigitizePolygonButton>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change some props on your code
You wrote disabilityState instead of disabledState

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabled="disabledState">
<slot name="slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel">text</slot>
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup(props) {
        return {
            disabledState: props.isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

In your parent-component, you should pass the isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled prop to the child component, not the disabledState.
Changes to your parent component:

```
<template>
    <DigitizePolygonButton :isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled="false">
        <template v-slot:slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel>
            <button>Test Button</button>
        </template>
    </DigitizePolygonButton>
</template>
```

Make those changes it should works.

Comment: would you please point out where in my code i used `disabledState`?!!

Answer (score 0):

this should be the solution:

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabilityState="digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState">
    <slot name="slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel">text</slot>
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup(props) {
        return {
            digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState: props.isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

You only need to change `isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled` in `button` tag to `digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState`

Comment: would you please tell me why should i change `isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled in button tag to digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState`? i think, i should use `:disabilityState="isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled"` because i want to bind on it from the parent component!! am i right please? please correct me

Comment: because that's the only variable that's only accessible in that component. So, whatever you're ```returning``` from ```setup()``` is what available for your html to use. And coincidentally, it's the only variable that you're returning

Comment: By the way, ```isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled ``` and ```digitizePolygonBtnDisabilityState``` is basically the same and has the same value, because they're referencing the same variable from parent